# Vue JS problems creating web components

Tags: vue.js, web-component

I am trying to create a web component from a vue component but I am having some issues.
The reason behind this is I am creating a new project with vue, but my manager wants me to be able to use all the components I'm writing to our existing project which is quite a complex web app, without any frameworks (only vanilla and jquery).

The problem I'm facing is when I try to do this with components which use third party libraries such as vuetify.
This simply does not work as expected and the styling is not being applied when I use the web component in a non-vue app.

Here is an example of one of these components:

```
<template>
  <v-card dark class="mx-auto"
    outlined>
    <v-card-title>
      {{title}}
    </v-card-title>
    <v-row>
      <v-col cols="sm" v-for="stat in stats" :key="stat.text">
        <div class="col pa-4">
          <h3>{{stat.value}}</h3>
          <h5 class=" text-uppercase">{{stat.text}}</h5>
        </div>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-card>
</template>

<script>
import {VCard, VCol, VRow} from 'vuetify'
export default {
  name: "StatusCard",
  props: {
    title: String,
    //stats: Array
  },
  components:{VCard, VCol,VRow},
  data: () => ({
      stats: [{text: 'test 1', value: 11}, {text: 'test 2', value: 22}]

  })
};
</script>

<style>
.small-icon {
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
</style>
```

This is how it looks in my **vue app**:

[image: component inside vue]

Now I run this line:

```
vue-cli-service build --target wc --inline-vue --name card-test src/components/StatusCard.vue
```

and I get all the files, when I start a simple HTTP server and serve the demo.html file that was created, this is what I get:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: vue components !== web components

Comment: i know that bro.... im trying to convert a vue component to a web component: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/build-targets.html#web-component

Comment: Where you are injecting your global styles ? Or you're only linking them in html ?

Comment: i do not have any global styles, im only using vuetify. so i was looking a little at my vue app, and i saw that vuetify actually injects the styling as global styles, maybe this is why its not working? because global styles will not be applied to shadow dom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK so i finally got this to work, in case any one else is having the same issue.
i just ended up importing the vuetify css inside my component:

```
<style>
@import '../../node_modules/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css';
</style>
```